# Reverse curve problem in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Reverse curve node does not work properly, it's written in the manual that shape's not affected, but it is not true to my situation

[image]

[image: without][image: with]

Comment: This does look strange. Please share this blend file with us, because the images alone are not enough to track down the problem.

Comment: @quellenform how would I add a file?

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, I have never seen such a curve.

Unfortunately, I can't answer you why Blender does that, and I don't know how you created that curve.

But one thing is for sure:

- It is indeed a Bezier curve with neatly aligned handles.
- There are no double points.
- It also seems to be fine in other respects.

But I can reproduce the behavior with *Blender 3.2* as well. ...could this be a bug?

Two possibilities:

- Either create a new curve
- Or put the node `Resample Curve` in between (*Evaluated*)

[image]

Comment: Besides geometry nodes, there is a way, I can just reverse it directly in edit mode, this won't give me an issue, but that resample curve is actually a way